# How the $-2t\cos(k)$ term appears in the dispersion of the $1D$ tight binding model?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, condensed-matter, operators, dispersion, tight-binding

I am trying to derive the tight binding dispersion relation with periodic boundary condition with $N$ lattice sites of the simplest Hamiltonian:
\begin{equation}
  \label{ham}
  \tag{1}
H = -t\sum\limits_{i}^N c_{i}^{\dagger} c_{i+1} +H.c.
\end{equation}
To represent the above equation in the momentum space, we should make the substitution:
\begin{equation}
  \label{mom-k}
  \tag{2}
\begin{aligned}
c_{i} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum\limits_{k} c_{k} e^{-\imath k r_{i}}\\
c_{i}^{\dagger} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum\limits_{k} c_{k}^{\dagger} e^{\imath k r_{i}}.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
With this substitution the first part of the Hamiltonian Eq. \eqref{ham} will give (we factored out the constant $1/N$)
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:1st}
  \tag{3}
  c_{i}^{\dagger} c_{i+1} = \sum\limits_k c_{k}^{\dagger} c_{k} e^{\imath k a}.
\end{equation}
Here, $a$ is the lattice constant. The hermitian conjugate of the above term will give
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:2nd}
  \tag{4}
  c_{i} c_{i+1}^{\dagger} = \sum\limits_k c_{k} c_{k}^{\dagger} e^{-\imath k a}.
\end{equation}
The total Hamiltonian, Eq. \eqref{ham} will be found by adding Eq. \eqref{eq:1st} and \eqref{eq:2nd}:
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:ham-k}
  \tag{5}
  H = -t \sum\limits_{k} \left[ c_{k}^{\dagger} c_{k} e^{\imath k a} + c_{k} c_{k}^{\dagger} e^{-\imath k a} \right].
\end{equation}
The problem arises after this step. The lecture notes and the books write (e.g. [this lect notes](https://bpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/u.osu.edu/dist/3/67057/files/2018/09/tight-binding_model_in_the_second_quantization_formalism-1egl8n3.pdf)):
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:ham-k-2}
  \tag{6}
  H = -t \sum\limits_{k} \left[ c_{k}^{\dagger} c_{k} e^{\imath k a} + c_{k} c_{k}^{\dagger} e^{-\imath k a} \right] = - t\sum\limits_{k} c_{k}^{\dagger} c_{k} \left[ e^{\imath k a} + e^{-\imath k a}\right] = -2t \sum\limits_{k} c_{k}^{\dagger} c_{k} \cos (ka).
\end{equation}
Above derivation is possible only if the fermion operators obey the rule $c^{\dagger}_{k} c_{k} = c_{k} c^{\dagger}_{k}$. However, this is by definition of the fermion operator is not possible.

**The dispersion relation containing $\cos (ka)$ can not be false, as all the condensed matter is based on this. Hence the question is, what am I missing in the derivation?**

Comment: The hermitian conjugate of $c_i^\dagger c_{i+1}$ is $c_{i+1}^\dagger c_i$.

Comment: Eqs. 3 and 4: are the sums to be understood?  Because otherwise those equations aren't correct.  And in writing $c_i$ as a sum over the $c_k$'s, there should be a factor of $1/\sqrt{N}$ (for the case of $N$ sites with periodic boundary conditions).

Comment: @TobiasFünke thank you for pointing out the mistake. I understood where i was going wrong.

Comment: @march yes you are correct there should be constant term (1/\sqrt{N}) and summation sign in Eq. 3 and 4. I decided to drop them for clarity of problem.

Comment: @kal92 "For clarity of the problem"- you should not do that (most importantly when you got a wrong result). For us it is not clear then what you understand and what not, and where you went wrong. If you present a problem to other people (strangers on the internet),  you have to understand that we don't know what you think or know -except for what you write in the question...

Comment: @TobiasFünke thank you for the suggestion. I have made the appropriate correction to the question.

Comment: @march I have made appropriate corrections to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it won't be important anymore but I still would like to clarify:

I guess you are refering to the beginning of page 6.

The step you are confused of is not using the commutator relations of fermionic operators but delta functions.
In the script there is $\sum_i\sum_{kk'}$ and a factor $e^{ir_ik}$ etc. The sum over the lattice site $\sum_i$ will produce a $\delta$-functional of the form $\delta(k-k')$ and with one of the sums $\sum_{k'}$ will be used to replace $k'$ by $k$. If you go over these steps carefully you will arrive at stated result.